# How to handle JavaScript popus with controls using Selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium

How to handle JavaScript popup with controls using Selenium webdriver C#

Could someone point me to some references on how to handle JS popups with controls (that has textbox and dropdowns) using Selenium web driver in C#?

Comment: JS popups are NOT recognized by driver.WindowHandles

Comment: If it is HTML dialog, you can manage it as same as normal elements in web page. What is your problem? Could you show your HTML, C# code, and error message?